# Change Stack Overflow login from Google SSO to proprietary

Tags: support, login

I created my Stack Overflow account some time ago allowing **Google Single Sign On** as the auth method. Now I want to switch to the native Stack Overflow authentication.

Is it possible without losing the account and its history?

Comment: Thanks for your support indicating me other similar questions with a valid answer, I searched either on search engines or within the site search, but probably using uneffective search terms. Regards.